# Grouping columns in angular UI grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have more than 50 columns in angular UI grid. Columns need to divided in to two group and I want two separate horizontal scroll bar. Is there any possibilities to achieve this in Angular UI Grid?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with the current design of grid... you may think of pinning or separating both the groups using CSS